# MTG. Using goblin chirurgeon's ability only for sacrifice

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I had a [Goblin Sharpshooter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Sharpshooter), sixty-some goblin tokens, and a [Goblin Chirurgeon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Chirurgeon) on the field (all with haste). My opponent had an enchantment that kept me from directly attacking him (2 life or {W} for each attacker), so I wanted to use my Chirurgeon's ability ("Sacrifice a Goblin: Regenerate target creature") to kill a creature which will untap my Sharpshooter. Do I NEED a regenerate target to sacrifice a goblin?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you must choose a valid target when activating a targeting ability. The ability says "target creature", so you must target a creature. Any creature will do<sup>[1]</sup>. Fortunately, you have plenty of valid targets (i.e. creatures), including your Goblin Sharpshooter and Goblin Chirurgeon (or even the token you are sacrificing, although that won't save it).

The following describes what happens in detail:

1. Activate Goblin Sharpshooter activated ability targeting your opponent.
2. Goblin Sharpshooter activated ability resolves

   1. Goblin Sharpshooter deals one damage to your opponent.
3. Activate Goblin Chirurgeon's ability targeting Goblin Sharpshooter, sacrificing a token.

   1. Goblin Sharpshooter's triggered ability triggers.
4. Goblin Sharpshooter's triggered ability is placed on the stack.
5. Goblin Sharpshooter's triggered ability resolves.

   1. Untap Goblin Sharpshooter.
6. Goblin Chirurgeon's ability resolves.

   1. Goblin Sharpshooter gains a regeneration shield.
7. Repeat.

Regenerating a creature grants it a shield that replaces its destruction the next time it would be destroyed that turn, if any. There's no requirement that you think it will be needed.

---

1. Unless an ability prevents it (e.g. "Protection from Red").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21832/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-mtg-using-goblin-chirurgeons-ability-only-for).